# Some classes could not be instantiated in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to the Android Language but i am familiar with the other programming languages.Today when i wanted to start building my first app from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html),when i created the project with the Android Studio i get this error massage:

```
Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:184)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:205)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:133)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296) Copy stack to clipboard
```

i try some of the solutions in the other stack questions but the problem does not solved.what should i do?

Comment: Possibly duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21815015/3111083

Comment: @sunilsunny this was not correct

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the answer is right there in your stack trace:
`You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

Try following the instructions in here:

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: This does not answer me

Comment: If you literally copy/paste the selected text into Google, you will have your answer. But fine, LMGTFY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity